# Missing model collection after submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi I have simple model which looks like this:

```
public class HomeModel
{
    public HomeModel()
    {
        Buildings = new List<Building>();
    }

    public List<Building> Buildings { get; set; }

    public int SelectedBuildingId { get; set; }

}
```

and on view i display combo like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedBuildingId, new SelectList(Model.Buildings, "Id", "Name"), "Choose Building... ")
```

and now when I click submit button, then the buildings list dissapears 
so I tryid to keep it with hidden field

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Buildings)
```

but it doesn't work, any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Buildings)** -> this is working just for primitive types like int string and so on.
I will not recommend you to serialize a list into the view but if this is necessary for you,you can do it like this:

```
           @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Buildings.Count; i++)
                {     
                  @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.Buildings[i])                      

                }
```

And now after post you will have full list in your view.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the list again... just load it again in the Post action.

**EDIT:**
If you insist in having it posted along with the important data. You should serialize that list to a string, and then rebuild the list in the server after the post.

Remember you are in MVC not plain ASP.NET... so each action is somehow atomic. For the case of dropdownlists, this is the normal behavior: reload the list in the server (independently from where you load it).

Comment: u mean get them again from db ? can't just keep it and not calling db again ?

Comment: Yes, you can keep it, but the view is not the way. Remember that it will be posted along. So... what you do is cache it in the server, to avoid going again to database. You can store it cache, session, file system.

Answer (score 0):

If your view is strongly typed to your `HomeModel`, then you can return your model in your postback event and return the model again to your view:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetHomePostResult(HomeModel model)
{
    //do whatever with your model data

    return View("YourHomeGetView", model);
}
```

Comment: It is strongly typed but simply the collection of buildings is empty after I click submit button , there is only SelectedBuildingId valid

Comment: Why do you need all the buildings to be posted to your server? Can't you just get them from your data base?

Comment: because this method I submit to returns me the same view and I need to bind buildings again

Answer (score 0):

**1)** 
`and now when I click submit button, then the buildings list dissapears so I tryid to keep it with hidden field`

`@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Buildings)`

`but it doesn't work, any help ?`

Just Inspect element and see what is the name rendered for this hidden field, Make sure you have the same name as in your Model (only then the values get binded). If you see a different name in element, change the syntax to

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Buildings, name {Name = Buildings })
```

and on post back the values will be binded in the model

```
                                  **OR**
```

2) If you are retrieving the values from DB using some Id or something. Pass this `Id` to the view.  And keep this in hidden field. On post back catch this value in controller with proper parameter name (Name must be same as the hidden field element in view). Use this Id to retrieve the DropDown again and continue...